# Does RTK has a "global" loading/fetching flag that listens to ALL data queries/mutations?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have the need of disabling filters and forms based on the status of the data queries and mutations of the application. Pretty much block the user interaction when something is being loaded or refreshed.

I am wondering if RTK Query, or just RTK, has a global fetching/loading status indicator?

Before RTK we had a global isLoading flag that we set to true any time a thunk fired. This is messy as there are so many instances of this action across the code.

Comment: None exists that I'm aware of. AFAIK each endpoint manages its own status, so you'll likely need to implement something yourself to collect up the status of anything that may be in a loading state.